# Where can I find the WMI documentation?

Tags: wmi

Google let me down, I couldn't find it on MSDN. `man wmi` doesn't work at the windows shell...
I'm looking for a list of objects that I can query, and how to construct the queries.

With WMI I mean the query language to query stuff like "Win32_Process"

I know about the classes and example queries, but I'm looking for a complete list of all possible query objects.

I already found what I'm looking for using the debugger, but it's still interesting to look at a complete overview to see what's possible with WMI.

Comment: Well, WMI can be a lot of things, could you please specify a bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use WMIViewer to browse WMI classes at http://iaas.ao-is.com/Download it is open source, and even generate powershell code for you.

Comment: That link is down. But there are other tools if one searches for "WMI explorer".

Answer (score 7):

[MSDN WIN32 Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394572(VS.85).aspx)
you can find a list of classes to use in your query here
along with example queries

Answer (score 7):

Do you know this tool [WMI Code Creator](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=2cc30a64-ea15-4661-8da4-55bbc145c30e&displaylang=en), good for learn WMI.
Another similar tool [Scriptomatic 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=12028).

Comment: Just wanted to say BIG THANKS for this link! Helped me a lot!

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a documented "complete" list of WMI classes that you can query, because programs can register their own WMI providers, and this can change between versions.

Use WBEMTEST and press the "Enum Classes" button...

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Query Language Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa392902.aspx), [Query Language Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394606(VS.85).aspx), and [the Main WMI Documentation page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft TechNet Script Center has [WMI Scripting Primer](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/guide/sas_wmi_overview.mspx) and many other hepful [WMI resources](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd742341.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

As Mentioned Previously WBEMTest is a good tool that is built into windows that helps you explore on top of msdn WMI Documentation.

Personally though I found WMI Studio to be the most complete tool helping understand What Each WMI class really does and how it behaves.

WMI Studio is a bit Studio. It runs as an ActiveX Addon For IE.

It might not be compilable with IE11 so you might have to turn off Enhanced Protection Mode in IE11 to get this working.

[WMI Studio.](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24045)

Answer (score 0):

I usually use [WMI Explorer](https://wmie.codeplex.com/) for my project [Services+](https://servicesplus.codeplex.com/) , contains full information about WMI queries and methods.