# Waiting for ShellExecuteEx (Setting access rights on Windows process)

Tags: c++, windows, process, shellexecute

I'm using the `ShellExecuteEx` function in a C++ program to launch an Uninstall.lnk file. In my program, I'd like to wait for the uninstaller to finish. My first attempt was to set the `SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS` flag in the `SHELLEXECUTEINFO` structure and then call `WaitForSingleObject` on the `hProcess` handle available in the `SHELLEXECUTEINFO` structure passed to `ShellExecuteEx`, but that still seemed to return way too early.

My current suspicion is that this is because the process launched by ShellExecuteEx (does it launch a new shell?) creates new child processes, but doesn't wait for them. So I'm trying to create a "wait for my child process and all the children it launches" function. To do so, I'm trying to use job objects.

I created a job object using `CreateJobObject`, assigned the process handle returned by `ShellExecuteEx` to the job and then attempted to wait for the job object. Unfortunately assigning the process to the job failed, and I think this is due to insufficient access rights.

Does anybody know how to set the PROCESS_SET_QUOTA and PROCESS_TERMINATE access rights (which are required for `AssignProcessToJobObject` to succeed, according to the MSDN) on a process handle, or another way to wait for the process launched by ShellExecuteEx to finish?

**UPDATE:** I should point out that I'm also launching other applications, not just `Uninstall.lnk`. One of them is e.g. a [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d(VS.80).aspx) application, which is effectively a simple XML file with the file extension `.application`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vista uses job objects for launching links. Therefor the process you try to assign to another job object might already be assigned.

See: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604522/performing-equivalent-of-kill-process-tree-in-c-on-windows/604527#604527)

Comment: Good point. Indeed, it seems as if sometimes (depending on the kind of file I launch via `ShellExecuteEx`), the launched process is already part of a job object. Unfortunately it's not possible to break this association. :-/

Comment: Good point. One of the reasons to use ShellExecuteEx is to hand of a whole bunch of responsibilities to the Shell. If you want more precise control, such as Job control, use CreateProcess.

Answer (score 1):

Why not to execute target file instead of openning `Uninstall.lnk`? You could use `IShellLink` to get shortcut target. Then you'll be able to execute target file via ShellExecuteEx using `SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS` flag.

Comment: If target process spawns another process (like msiexec.exe) and dies, this won't help.

Comment: Then you should to execute `msiexec.exe` or even better to use installer API.

Comment: I'm sorry for the imprecision; I'm also launching other types of files, not just .lnk files. I also launch ordinary .exe files as well as ClickOnce applications (.application files).