# How to monitor a process call in windows using C++

Tags: c++

**My situation :**

Process A will call process B, that means process B is the child process of process A.

How we can capture what process will be called by process A?

**Example**
Process A : bcc55.exe hello.c

Will automatically call process B : ilink32.exe
Now give you the process A, how to find the process B.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173342/terminate-a-process-tree-c-for-windows/1173396#1173396)** to see how to enumerate child processes for a given windows process ID.  You can first get the process ID by EXE name using the code **[here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2702/How-to-get-handle-to-any-running-process-by-its-na)**

Answer (score 0):

You can hook the various `CreateProcess*` functions, run your own code (perhaps to record what's been called) and then call the original function with the same parameters. It can get fiddly though :)