# Process Object from Apache Commons Exec

Tags: java, apache-commons-exec

I'm using the Apache Commons Exec jars for creating processes. However I'd like to get control of the process id of processes being invoked.

Is there a way of getting the 'Process' object from the Apache Commons Exec api? I did'nt fine any public methods that returns the 'Process class.

Answer (score 0):

See http://commons.apache.org/exec/apidocs/index.html

Interface CommandLauncher contains several `exec` methods that return `Process`.

But anyway you do not have any way to control the process ID: it is the OS responsibility. Moreover standard java API does not allow you even to retrieve the process ID. There was a trick in older java versions: the implementation of Process contained int field pid that could be retrieved using reflection. But this was changed in version 1.6.

Comment: Thanks for the information. The process object is related to another question I had asked here . I'm using JNA as described here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912282/java-tool-method-to-force-kill-a-child-process/6032734#6032734) to retrieve the process id and kill the entire process tree using the taskkill command of windows.