# In C#, how to kill a process tree reliably

Tags: c#, process

In C#, we use the following code to kill a process tree.
Sometimes it works, and sometimes it doesn't, possibly having to do with Windows 7 and/or 64-bit.

The way it finds children of the given process is by calling `GetProcesses` to get all the processes in the system, and then calling `NtQueryInformationProcess` to find out every process whose parent is the given process.
It does this recursively, to walk the tree.

The on-line doc says `NtQueryInformationProcess` should not be used.
Instead there is something called `EnumProcesses`, but I can't find any examples in C#, only other languages.

What's a reliable way to kill a tree of processes in C#?

```
    public static void TerminateProcessTree(Process process)
    {
        IntPtr processHandle = process.Handle;
        uint processId = (uint)process.Id;

        // Retrieve all processes on the system
        Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
        foreach (Process proc in processes)
        {
            // Get some basic information about the process
            PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION procInfo = new PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION();
            try
            {
                uint bytesWritten;
                Win32Api.NtQueryInformationProcess(proc.Handle, 0, ref procInfo,
                    (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(procInfo), out bytesWritten); // == 0 is OK

                // Is it a child process of the process we're trying to terminate?
                if (procInfo.InheritedFromUniqueProcessId == processId)
                {
                    // Terminate the child process (and its child processes)
                    // by calling this method recursively
                    TerminateProcessTree(proc);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception /* ex */)
            {
                // Ignore, most likely 'Access Denied'
            }
        }

        // Finally, terminate the process itself:
        if (!process.HasExited)
        {
            try
            {
                process.Kill();
            }
            catch { }
        }
    }
```

Comment: [Performing equivalent of "Kill Process Tree" in c++ on windows](http://stackoverflow.com/q/604522) (clearly you already know how to P/Invoke)

Comment: Your question reduces to "How to find all child processes". Killing them is a trivial extension of the problem. This is therefore a duplicate.

Comment: @usr: Thanks for flagging that. I'm still trying to figure out what `using` statement to use.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey not sure what you mean. Sounds like a simple research task, whatever it is. If you can't do it, ask a new question.

Comment: Uhh, the question I linked is a *way* better choice if we're closing this as a duplicate. But I specifically didn't vote to close, because it isn't an exact duplicate of either question. For one thing, it uses a different language. Even if translating the code is trivial, it's not a duplicate. (Mike, I don't know what you mean either by trying to figure out what `using` statement to use. Is that your way of saying you're hopelessly lost? If you're completely new to .NET, you might want to mention that. I made some assumptions looking at your rep. ;-))

Comment: @Cody: Rep is more a matter of time-on-site and general busyness. I'm still pretty new to .Net.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `ManagmentObjectSearcher` and a little recursion:

```
private static void KillProcessAndChildren(int pid)
{
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher
      ("Select * From Win32_Process Where ParentProcessID=" + pid);
    ManagementObjectCollection moc = searcher.Get();
    foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
    {
        KillProcessAndChildren(Convert.ToInt32(mo["ProcessID"]));
    }
    try
    {
        Process proc = Process.GetProcessById(pid);
        proc.Kill();
    }
    catch (ArgumentException)
    {
        // Process already exited.
    }
 }
```

Comment: Excuse my naivete', but I tried `using System.Management;` and that didn't seem to give me access to it. I must be missing something.

Comment: Did you add a reference to `System.Management.dll`?

Comment: Wouldn't you want to kill the parent process first to avoid it restarting processes?

Comment: That's how `Process.Kill(bool)` does it: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/2f6f3c55e4c230ac9134abeaef494c17c01c97f7/src/libraries/System.Diagnostics.Process/src/System/Diagnostics/Process.Win32.cs#L386
(That method is new since this question was asked.)