# LibreOffice Stopped working , while converting XLS to XHTML files using C# application

Tags: c#, windows, libreoffice, unoconv

[image]

In this, my queries are,

- How to handle LibreOffice Exceptions in C#.
- If could not handle , how to pro-grammatically close this exception or to suppress this exception popup, while excuting console

  - OR any better solution, that my conversion process , should not stop because of unhandle exception caused by Libre Office.

Comment: Use a try catch clause to get a more specific error would be a start

Comment: If what you're asking is how to handle exceptions, you should take a look at the try...catch statement.

Comment: What is the line in your C# code where the error occurs -- is it a system call perhaps?

Comment: Try Catch block didn't help, as i called libreOffice , via unoconv(3rd party tool), so when exception occurs in libreOffice, it's unhandled by python as well as c# code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, thank you all for your kind help.. :). Finally i resolved.

While bulk file conversion , my c# process, was getting interrupted , because of some exception occurred in LibreOffice process(soffice). so i started killing my c# process and its child processes and also killed soffice. So for next file, fresh soffice is getting created , as i executed unoconv command.

but still, i get the exception popup, but the c# process , keeps continue..
[this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23845395/in-c-how-to-kill-a-process-tree-reliably) helped me

Answer (score 1):

From the image, it looks like the exception got thrown from [storeToUrl()](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/frame/XStorable.html#storeToURL) in the code at https://github.com/caolanm/unoconv/blob/master/unoconv.

`unoconv` is a command line tool, not a library, so it does not seem possible to catch the error with a try/catch block.  Perhaps you could capture the process's error stream and parse it to see if an exception occurred.

Instead of using `unoconv`, it may be better to call `storeToUrl()` directly in C# using the UNO API, with a try/catch for [com.sun.star.io.IOException](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/io/IOException.html).

When doing many automated conversions with LibreOffice, it is typically necessary to kill the process whenever it gets stuck: https://github.com/dagwieers/unoconv/issues/352.