# WMI Cheatsheet?

Tags: windows, wmi

Is there a cheatsheet available for WMI? Like what can be queried, where to query it from?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483501/where-can-i-find-the-wmi-documentation

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's a ton of information available to query. I think that the best way is just to enumerate everything and have a look.

Try Microsoft's [WMI Code Creator](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=2cc30a64-ea15-4661-8da4-55bbc145c30e&displaylang=en) application. It helps you build queries in a few languages, so is sort of an interactive cheatsheet.

I also remember finding the "`wbemtest`" application useful.

I think it's included with Windows, so try Start > Run > wbemtest.

Answer (score 2):

I have found [WMI Explorer](http://www.ks-soft.net/hostmon.eng/wmi/index.htm) very helpful in finding classes and methods-- it's a lot more elegant than WEBMtest

Comment: it's wbemtest, not webmtest

Answer (score 1):

You can use WMI Browser in the WMI administrative tools. You can search for the classes, query the classes etc.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=6430F853-1120-48DB-8CC5-F2ABDC3ED314&displaylang=en

Comment: the broken link ("We are sorry, the page you requested cannot be found."), makes this answer little useful.